# Trouble with Eclipse Android Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to run an Android application on the emulator. When I run the application from Eclipse, it prompts me to pick the emulator, but when I actually run it, nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share some more details? Do you see any kind of error in the logcat when you launch the emulator?

Comment: Actually, running `adb kill-server`, `adb start-server` in cmd may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Go to Eclipse-> window-> Android Virtual Device Manager

If you have created a AVD ,it will be visible there, Select it and Click on Start on Right Side

This should launch your AVD

After Launching AVD, run you application on it